# What does the CorrectionList command do in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, command

I'm in the process of learning WPF and am currently looking into application commands (e.g., ApplicationCommands.Copy). I found a list of recognized [application commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms616819.aspx) on MSDN. All of them made sense except for CorrectionList. What is this command and what kind of scenario would invoke it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just click the link in your provided link:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.applicationcommands.correctionlist.aspx

"The correction list is different depending on the context. For example, with Input Method Editor (IME) input the correction list identifies reconversion choices.

There is not necessarily an implementation for the command on any given object; in many cases the implementation for the command is the responsibility of the application writer."

Comment: I did see the text you quoted. I guess that because I use English on computers located in the US, I wouldn't be likely to encounter a correction list.